# Permuting Through Certain Blocks of a Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, permutation

**On the diagonal I have n+1, nxn blocks of zeros, but then in the other n  blocks on that row, I have a certain matrix.**

See picture here:

[image]

What I want to do with these P blocks is have a list of the matrices I would like to try in each one of these Pn blocks and test for certain matrix properties.

These are my troubles:
1. Finding a way to make a list of matrices I would like to iterate through. (I am new to MATLAB and this doesn't come as easy as other languages like python)
2. Making a nested loop that tries each permutation of my matrix with each of the P blocks different possible matrices.

To clarify each P has the same possible matrices. **This list of possible matrices is of size n!.**

This seems like a rather simple task that I am struggling incredibly with. 
So far I only have:

```
 %For n = 2
 Pa = [1 0; 0 1];
 Pb = [0 1; 1 0];
 Z = [0 0; 0 0];

 row1 = [Z Pa Pa];
 row2 = [Pa Z Pa];
 row3 = [Pa Pa Z];

 C = [row1; row2; row3];

 trc = trace(C*C*C);
 if trc == 0
 disp(C);
 end

 %Now need to try Pb for one of the Pa
```

Yes, very naive. Obviously I would like `Pa` and `Pb` in one list that I would be able to iterate through on the matrix.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: To clarify: if you have 6 nonzero blocks (as in the picture) and a list of 3 matrices, you would like to get all 3^6 possible compound matrices, right?

Comment: Yes exactly right. For each n I have I would be finding n^(n!) possible matrices.

Comment: Why n^(n!)? If the list contains m matrices, the total number of compound matrices is m^(n*(n-1)), isn't it? n*(n-1) is the number of nonzero blocks, and each block contains a matrix from the list

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that properly, let me make some edit and then reply to you in one second.

Comment: If the list contains n! matrices, the total number of resulting big matrices is n!^(n*(n-1)). Am i right?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry for the confusion. I should have added m = n!. So there would be (size of matrix list)^(number of nonzero blocks). Yes.

Comment: Now I'm confused again. Your updated image does not have n, nxn blocks of zeros. It has n+1, nxn blocks of zeros.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that! In my code I had it correctly, but in my inital description and image I had the matrix of incorrect size.

Comment: in your example C = kron(~eye(3), Pa)

Comment: That's very effective for getting C = kron(~eye(n),Pa) and C = kron(~eye(n),Pb). But I also need the cases where some of the non diagonals are Pa and some of them are Pb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- Answer to your question *before the edit* (there are n x n blocks, each block has n x n entries):**

```
n = 3; 
example = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
matrices = cat(3, example, 10*example, 100*example);
%// This is the list. Each third-dim slice is a matrix

[aux{1:n}] = deal(ones(n));
nz = ~blkdiag(aux{:}); %// template for filling result matrix
m = size(matrices,3); %// number of matrices in list
T = n^2; %// size of result matrix
N = n*(n-1); %// number of blocks
for ii = 0:m^N-1 %// number of results  
    ind = dec2base(ii,m,N)-'0'+1; %// indices of matrices to be used
    result = zeros(T); %// initiallize to zeros
    result(nz) = permute(reshape(matrices(:,:,ind),[n n n-1 n]),[1 3 2 4]);
    %// fill in matrices given by ind
    disp(result)
end
```

In this example I'm using a list of 3 matrices, and `n` is 3. So there are 729 results. Here are the first few:

```
 0     0     0     1     2     3     1     2     3
 0     0     0     4     5     6     4     5     6
 0     0     0     7     8     9     7     8     9
 1     2     3     0     0     0     1     2     3
 4     5     6     0     0     0     4     5     6
 7     8     9     0     0     0     7     8     9
 1     2     3     1     2     3     0     0     0
 4     5     6     4     5     6     0     0     0
 7     8     9     7     8     9     0     0     0

 0     0     0     1     2     3     1     2     3
 0     0     0     4     5     6     4     5     6
 0     0     0     7     8     9     7     8     9
 1     2     3     0     0     0    10    20    30
 4     5     6     0     0     0    40    50    60
 7     8     9     0     0     0    70    80    90
 1     2     3     1     2     3     0     0     0
 4     5     6     4     5     6     0     0     0
 7     8     9     7     8     9     0     0     0

 0     0     0     1     2     3     1     2     3
 0     0     0     4     5     6     4     5     6
 0     0     0     7     8     9     7     8     9
 1     2     3     0     0     0   100   200   300
 4     5     6     0     0     0   400   500   600
 7     8     9     0     0     0   700   800   900
 1     2     3     1     2     3     0     0     0
 4     5     6     4     5     6     0     0     0
 7     8     9     7     8     9     0     0     0

 0     0     0     1     2     3    10    20    30
 0     0     0     4     5     6    40    50    60
 0     0     0     7     8     9    70    80    90
 1     2     3     0     0     0     1     2     3
 4     5     6     0     0     0     4     5     6
 7     8     9     0     0     0     7     8     9
 1     2     3     1     2     3     0     0     0
 4     5     6     4     5     6     0     0     0
 7     8     9     7     8     9     0     0     0

 0     0     0     1     2     3    10    20    30
 0     0     0     4     5     6    40    50    60
 0     0     0     7     8     9    70    80    90
 1     2     3     0     0     0    10    20    30
 4     5     6     0     0     0    40    50    60
 7     8     9     0     0     0    70    80    90
 1     2     3     1     2     3     0     0     0
 4     5     6     4     5     6     0     0     0
 7     8     9     7     8     9     0     0     0
```

**2- Modifications in order to answer your question *after the edit* (there are (n+1) x (n+1) blocks, each block has n x n entries):**

As per your edit, the number of blocks is now larger. In this case I'm using an example with `n=2`.

```
n = 2; 
matrices = cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40], [100 200; 300 400]);
%// This is the list. Each third-dim slice is a matrix

[aux{1:n+1}] = deal(ones(n));
nz = ~blkdiag(aux{:}); %// template for filling result matrix
m = size(matrices,3); %// number of matrices in list
T = n*(n+1); %// size of result matrix
N = (n+1)*n; %// number of blocks
R = m^N; %// number of results  
for ii = 0:R-1
    ind = dec2base(ii,m,N)-'0'+1; %// indices of matrices to be used
    result = zeros(T); %// initiallize to zeros
    result(nz) = permute(reshape(matrices(:,:,ind),[n n n n+1]),[1 3 2 4]);
    %// fill in matrices given by ind
    disp(result)
end
```

First few results:

```
 0     0     1     2     1     2
 0     0     3     4     3     4
 1     2     0     0     1     2
 3     4     0     0     3     4
 1     2     1     2     0     0
 3     4     3     4     0     0

 0     0     1     2     1     2
 0     0     3     4     3     4
 1     2     0     0    10    20
 3     4     0     0    30    40
 1     2     1     2     0     0
 3     4     3     4     0     0

 0     0     1     2     1     2
 0     0     3     4     3     4
 1     2     0     0   100   200
 3     4     0     0   300   400
 1     2     1     2     0     0
 3     4     3     4     0     0

 0     0     1     2    10    20
 0     0     3     4    30    40
 1     2     0     0     1     2
 3     4     0     0     3     4
 1     2     1     2     0     0
 3     4     3     4     0     0

 0     0     1     2    10    20
 0     0     3     4    30    40
 1     2     0     0    10    20
 3     4     0     0    30    40
 1     2     1     2     0     0
 3     4     3     4     0     0
```

Comment: Wow that's beautiful. I am pretty sure this is exacty what I will need to utilize. I think this does exactly what I poorly described it needing it to do (sorry!) I will test it out and report back.

Comment: This answer applies to your first image, not the second (when there were fewer blocks). Is that a problem?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. I will need to go thru and learn all these functions you used.

Comment: I don't think it should be. If I can't figure out how to apply it to larger or smaller matrices on my own I shouldn't be in programming at all.

Comment: Your last comment is great, and I totally agree. Still, I've been figuring out what should be changed to match your second image (where the number of blocks is larger). I'm including it as a second part to my answer

Comment: Luis I was wondering if you could please explain how you chose the values in: "matrices(:,:,ind),[n n n n+1]),[1 3 2 4]" if I go for say n = 6, it should be 1 3 2 4 5 6, and n n n n n n+1 right?

Comment: I was able to figure everything out. However, this becomes very computationally expensive as the list of possible matrices increases. I realized the solution I am looking, for as many n as my computational power will allow me, has to be symmetric. So I had an idea to define the lower triangular blocks as the inverse of the upper triangular blocks.